# Starting at Web Service

Tags: java, sql, service, web

I want to start writing a web service which will most probably using Microsoft SQL for Database.

I am unsure how to start about it since I have never written web service before. I know SQL for database. Java for programming as well but no information regarding web service. I am quick learner and wish to know how shall I start ?

What my project will do is get data from database and post in a front end. I chose Web Service as it uses XML and most compatible with many interfaces.

please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web service uses a web server as a container to run in.  I suggest that you look at Tomcat as a easy but reliable web server.  In the Tomcat web server you can make a web service by using jsp and servlets (written in Java).

try having a look at http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can use the book "OReilly Head First Servlet and JSP" to learn about Web Services in Java.. Thats what i did.